# Can printf suspend after printing half the contents

Tags: c, linux

Can `printf` suspend in the middle of printing an output? If yes can someone provide me a relevant context. For e.g

Is it possible that following `printf()` prints
`printf("Hello World\n")`

First prints `"H"`
then sleeps for say 10 second and then print `"ello World"`

Comment: What do you mean by "can"? You want to do this? Or are you afraid this will happen randomly? Or what?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.
Since you are using `printf` (and not `fprintf`) the output will be placed on the standard output, now if you redirect your output to a file/device that blocks writes then this simple call to `printf` can sleep for e.g. 10 seconds.

Scenario:

- create echo.c:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  main() {
       printf("Hello World\n");
  }
  ```
- create a named fifo:

  ```
  mkfifo fifo
  ```
- compile echo.c:

  ```
  make echo
  ```
- run echo and redirect its output to `fifo`:

  ```
  ./echo > fifo
  ```
- this blocks until some other process reads the `fifo` file, so after 10 seconds in a different shell run:

  ```
  cat fifo
  ```
- only then the `echo` program is able to continue and write "Hello World\n" to the `fifo` file

Comment: thanks for giving such a good example. I totally missed this aspect :)

Answer (score 2):

printf ultimately calls write(). If the write() system call returns a -1 because the system call received EINTR, for example, then it is possible for some data to have been written. However, the tty (screen) is line buffered.  This means nothing appears on the screen until a `\n` character is placed on the output stream.

The EINTR would happen on a system that is being really hammered by I/O, for example.  Because write() is not guaranteed to complete, it can be interrupted.

So, I do not get what you are seeing.  What problem do you see?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually I see a problem where printf suspends and gives a crash while resuming. I don't know yet what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own version of `printf` (say `printf_delay`) which takes your string to print, and iterates over each character, printing and then sleeping for a specified length of time.

e.g.:

```
void printf_delay(char* str, unsigned int delay){
    int c=0;
    while (str[c] != '\0'){
        /* Print character */
        /* Sleep for */
        /* Increment c */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions:

1. Simply divide `printf()` into two `printf()`'s

   ```
   printf("H");
   sleep(10);
   printf("ello World\r\n");
   ```
2. Another way is to rewrite the `putc()` function. It is used by `printf()` to output     characters, so if you add some delay in `putc()` you'll get your 10 seconds between symbols  are printed. **Note:** this delay will be implemented to any of your characters, not for only one and once.

   ```
   int putc(int c, FILE *fp){
       char ch;
       ch = c;
       write(fp->fd, &ch, 1);
       sleep(10);
       return(c);
   }

   int main(){
       char test[] = "Hello World\r\n";
       printf("%s", test);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

PS: I took `putc()` source from some internet page, please recheck it before using (maybe find any other `putc()` implementation).